# Orbit Controls follow the mouse without clicking three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Does anyone have a code to force orbit controls in three.js to move the scene on mousemove instead of click + mousemove I've tried using the answer in this thread:
[How to recreate the Three.js OrbitControl movement on mouse move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357130/how-to-recreate-the-three-js-orbitcontrol-movement-on-mouse-move)
but sadly it throws an error "Maximum call stack size exceeded error" and I just get a black canvas with nothing in it...

I also tried changing

```
scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
```

to

```
scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseDown, false );
```

In the OrbitControls.js file but that seems to freeze when moving and stops every now and again...

Has anyone managed to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Couldn't you just use `FirstPersonControls` like in this example? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shadowmap

Comment: There's also the thing that the cursor stops moving at the edge of the window.. (but you could fix that with pointerlock).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this; https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/e3b501cw/51/

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    let scale = -0.01;
    orbit.rotateY( e.movementX * scale );
    orbit.rotateX( e.movementY * scale ); 
    orbit.rotation.z = 0; //this is important to keep the camera level..
})
    
//the camera rotation pivot
orbit = new THREE.Object3D();
orbit.rotation.order = "YXZ"; //this is important to keep level, so Z should be the last axis to rotate in order...
orbit.position.copy( mesh.position );
scene.add(orbit );

//offset the camera and add it to the pivot
//you could adapt the code so that you can 'zoom' by changing the z value in camera.position in a mousewheel event..
let cameraDistance = 1;
camera.position.z = cameraDistance;
orbit.add( camera );
```

Use an Object3D that acts as a pivot for the camera. It rotates on mouse movement.

EDIT: I found my own answer but found a way. You **can** enable auto rotate with the mouse position, but you have to make OrbitControl's `handleMouseMoveRotate` public, by copying the function and setting it as `this.handleMouseMoveRotate`.
Then in setup you add an event listener and send the event to the controls.

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( e )=>{
    controls.handleMouseMoveRotate( e ) 
});
```

And make sure to set `controls.enableRotate = false;`

Comment: I ended up editing the OrbitControls.js and replace the mouse down function with a cheeky mouse over listener

Comment: WTF... 
I was looking up how to rotate the orbitcontrols without clicking, and found my own answer...